# Creation of bigrams in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

I have a list of candidate bilingual terms extracted from the parallel corpus, in this format

```
Difensori dei diritti umani, libertà di espressione >>> Human rights defenders, freedom of expression
```

What I want is to associate in bigrams the item in both languages. So every multi word term in the source language (Italian) will be associated in bigram with every multi word term in the target language (English). So for the example the bigrams will look like this:

```
('Difensori dei diritti umani','Human rights defenders')
('Difensori dei diritti umani','freedom of expression')
('libertà di espressione','Human rights defenders')
('libertà di espressione','freedom of expression')
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Sorry is this a pure pairing of list items or you have to check the language?

Comment: So what you want is simply the Cartesian product of the grams of both sentences and not an alignment of equivalent phases (that is one of the problems in the field of machine translation).

Comment: This is a cartesian product and string problem, what have you tried till now ?

Comment: Why are you asking for bigrams when the output shows trigrams??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit of wrangling to get what you need. If you only want translation based tuples, based on your example, you could use the following function:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def zipping(string):
    string = string.replace(', ', ',')   # to take away parasite spaces
    string = string.split(" >>> ")
    trans_tuples = zip(string[0].split(','), string[1].split(','))
    return trans_tuples

str = "Difensori dei diritti umani, libertà di espressione >>> Human rights defenders, freedom of expression"
for bigram in zipping(str):
    print bigram
```

Output will be:

```
('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'Human rights defenders')
('libertà di espressione', 'freedom of expression')
```

If you need to associate both terms in one side, with both terms from the other side (for context purposes I suppose), just adjust the zipping function as follow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def zipping(string):
    string = string.replace(', ', ',')
    string = string.split(" >>> ")
    trans_tuples = zip(string[0].split(','), string[1].split(','))
    trans_tuples.append((trans_tuples[0][0], trans_tuples[1][1]))  # new line 1
    trans_tuples.append((trans_tuples[1][0], trans_tuples[0][1]))  # new line 2
    return trans_tuples

str = "Difensori dei diritti umani, libertà di espressione >>> Human rights defenders, freedom of expression"
for bigram in zipping(str):
    print bigram
```

In that case, the output would be as follow:

```
('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'Human rights defenders')
('libertà di espressione', 'freedom of expression')
('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'freedom of expression')
('libertà di espressione', 'Human rights defenders')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what your are looking for ?

```
s = "Difensori dei diritti umani, liberta di espressione >>> Human rights defenders, freedom of expression"

bigrams = []
trans = s.split(' >>> ')
for it in trans[0].split(', '):
    for en in trans[1].split(', '):
        bigrams.append((it, en))
        print((it, en))
```

It produces this output:

```
('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'Human rights defenders')  
('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'freedom of expression')  
('liberta di espressione', 'Human rights defenders')   
('liberta di espressione','freedom of expression')
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
str = "Difensori dei diritti umani, libertà di espressione >>> Human rights defenders, freedom of expression"
b = [elem.split(", ") for elem in str.split(" >>> ")]
bigrams = list(zip(b[0], b[1]))
bigrams_ = list((zip(reversed(b[0]), b[1])))
bigrams = bigrams + bigrams_
for bigram in bigrams:
    print(bigram)
```

Output:

```
('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'Human rights defenders')
('libertà di espressione', 'freedom of expression')
('libertà di espressione', 'Human rights defenders')
('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'freedom of expression')
```

Comment: where are the bigrams?